# iOS RestKit Framework - crashing after sent request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http, restkit

my code:

```
RKRequest.m:

#import "RKRequestDelegate.h"
#import "Constants.h"


@implementation RKRequestDelegate {

}

- (void)sendRequest:(UIImageView *)imageView {

    NSDictionary *queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"w", @"4", @"section", @"0",
                                                                           @"latitude", @"0", @"longitude", @"0", @"dt", @"0", @"di", nil];
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[Constants getSettingsName]
            ofType:[Constants getSettingsFormat]];
    NSDictionary *contentDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSString *addedUrl = [contentDictionary valueForKey:[Constants getBannerTag]];
    //

    RKRequest *request = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:addedUrl queryParameters:queryParams delegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Response!!!");
}


@end

RKRequestDelegate.h:

@interface RKRequestDelegate : NSObject <RKRequestDelegate>

- (void)sendRequest:(UIImageView *)UIImageView;
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response;

@end

AppDelegate.m:

    RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[HttpUtil getHost]];
```

After launch application it's crashes after 5 seconds. If I change `delegate:self` to delegate:`[RKRequestDelegate class]` it does not crash, and gives response 200 (OK), but it did not callback a `didLoadResponse`!

Please help, and thanks.

UPDATE:

If I use `[request sendSynchronously];` in RKRequestDelegate.m, response gets called.

Comment: You crash is almost definitely because your delegate is being freed too early.

Answer (score 2):

Make `request` a class variable.

EDIT: Here's some code, didn't check it in real life, but this way should work

```
   @interface MYRequests : NSObject<RKRequestDelegate>
   {
       RKRequest *request;
   }

   @implementation MYRequests
   - (void)loginRequest
   {
       request = [RKRequest ...];
       request.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
       request.delegate = self;
       [request send];
   }
   @end
```

Comment: I add request in 

@implementation BannerRKRequestDelegate {
...
}

but does not work

Comment: It should be in @interface section, do you mean so?

Comment: No, same problem, only [request sendSynchronously] can fix this.


I start this request on start application (Main Screen), method viewDidLoad, this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is almost definitely because your delegate is being freed too early. If you don't feel like learning proper memory management, try moving to the blocks equivalent: [RKClient get:usingBlock:] and you might get lucky.